# Refactor python: replace list of words in list of strings

Tags: python, regex, refactoring

Still getting my head around python, I wonder if this function could be improved either in performance or readability?

```
def multi_replace_words(sentences, words, replace_str):
    """Replace all words in the sentences list with replace_str
    ex. multi_replace_words(['bad a list', 'og bad', 'in bady there bad2', 'another one', 'and bad. two'], ['bad','bad2']', 'EX')
    >> ['EX a list', 'og EX', 'in bady there EX','another one','and EX two']
    """
    docs = []
    for doc in sentences:
        for replace_me in words:
            if(replace_me in doc.encode('ascii', 'ignore')):
                doc = re.sub('((\A|[^A-Za-z0-9_])'+replace_me+'(\Z|[^A-Za-z0-9_]))', ' ' + replace_str+' ', doc)
        docs.append(doc)
    return docs
```

Thanks :)

Comment: I would start be renaming ds and cls to be slightly more descriptive parameter names.

Comment: you're right. i just changed the variable names to better indicate the function's purpose from ds, cls to sentences, words. they were just shortnames for dataset & classes (as in features in nlp) in my app.

Comment: don't you keep the punctuation?

Comment: no. it's one step in a preprocessing pipeline to identify swear words, including punctuation, and variations like bad-, |bad| and others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
In [86]: def func(lis,a,b):
    strs= "|".join("({0}{1}{2})".format(r'\b',x,r'\b[;",.]?') for x in a)
    for x in lis:
        yield re.sub(strs,b,x)
   ....:         

In [87]: lis
Out[87]: ['bad a list', 'og bad', 'in bady there bad2', 'another one', 'and bad. two']

In [88]: rep=['bad','bad2']

In [89]: st="EX"

In [90]: list(func(lis,rep,st))
Out[90]: ['EX a list', 'og EX', 'in bady there EX', 'another one', 'and EX two']

In [91]: rep=['in','two','a']

In [92]: list(func(lis,rep,st))
Out[92]: ['bad EX list', 'og bad', 'EX bady there bad2', 'another one', 'and bad. EX']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use replace().  It acts on a string and replaces all instances of a series of characters with another.  An example from [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm) shows how replace acts.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

str = "this is string example....wow!!! this is really string";
print str.replace("is", "was");
print str.replace("is", "was", 3);
```

Comment: that would also replace partial text inside words, like the is in this

Comment: If you wanted to make sure to only replace full words without creating mix ups like in the example above you could add spaces before and after the words still in the quotes.  Like this " is ".